# JQuery Clone is cloning final row's data

Tags: jquery, clone

I am running into a problem. I was using:

```
$(this).parents("tr:first").remove();
```

to delete the row the user clicked on and then:

```
var row = $('#picTableDisplay tbody>tr:last').clone(true)
            .insertAfter('#picTableDisplay tbody>tr:last');
```

to replace a new (empty) row at the bottom of the table.

But, when the table is full (12 rows) and the user wants to remove a row, 
the bottom table (that has data) gets cloned (with the data).

In this scenario, how do I remove the clicked on row and add a row to the 
bottom of the table that is empty?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be doing exactly what you've told it to do... cloning the last row, with or without data.
The solution is simple - don't do it.

1. Clone a last invisible row (so you have 13 rows), or
2. Clone the row from a template you keep on the side, eg:

   ```
   $('#RowTemplate tr').clone(true).show()
   ```
3. Another option is to copy the row when the page is loaded, and then recloning it:

   ```
   var rowTemplate = $('#picTableDisplay tbody>tr:last').clone(true)

   $('#picTableDisplay tr').click(function(){
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      var row = rowTemplate.clone(true) //...
   });
   ```

Please also note there's a known bug with cloning the last element on IE, as detailed here: [Problem using jQuery clone function in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560889/problem-using-jquery-clone-function-in-form/1592831#1592831).